# Import PayPal-iOS-SDK in swift project

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to use PayPal-iOS-SDK in my swift project.

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

I use CocoaPods and set LSApplicationQueriesSchemes to info.plist.

But I still got "Use of unresolved identifier 'PayPalMobile'" error in AppDelegate.swift.

```
PayPalMobile .initializeWithClientIds(forEnvironments: [PayPalEnvironmentProduction: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                                                            PayPalEnvironmentSandbox: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"])
```

Do I have to do more process to use PayPal-iOS-SDK?

Comment: have you tried `import PayPalMobile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, that you missed some steps in order to use an external library. In case you set LSApplicationQueriesSchemes right, have you included this lines inside your podfile?

```
pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK'
```

After that, you should call `pod install` from your CLI inside your project's path.

To use this library you need to use imports, as @Scriptable mentioned.

```
import PayPalMobile
```

Wrote this on the top of your file where you need to use it.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I wrote pod 'PayPal-iOS-SDK' in Podfile. and I did 'pod install'. And I add 'import PayPalMobile' in my swift file, I got 'No such module 'PayPalMobile'' error. What else do I need? Please give me an advice.

Comment: Are you using Objective-C or Swift in your project?

Comment: Check this out. The issue seems very similar to yours - https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/512

Comment: Thank you for an advice. I added bridging head file and I remove 'import PayPalMobile', it works.

Comment: haha I did not know I have to do pod install

Answer (score 0):

Create a new header file with the correct name -Bridging-Header.h
and add:

## import "PayPalMobile.h"